# Data not posting when clicking on submit button

Tags: php, html

Here is my code, earlier it was working but now it is not working. Nothing is happening when I click on the submit button, the page is not reloading.

```
<table align="center" border="0" width="1100">
    <tr>
        <td class="td_text" align="center">
            <form method="post" action="exam.php">
                <b>Select exam : </b>
                <select name="exams"  style="width:150px;height:30px;">
                    <option> SBI </option>
                    <option> IBPS </option>
                    <option> RBI </option>
                    <option> SSC </option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" style="width:150px;height:30px; border:2px solid black;"  onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" >
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide your js code as well and also check the errors in console

Comment: Programatically there is nothing wrong with that code. There must be a problem elsewhere in your code. Have you looked at the dev console in Chrome or Firefox (Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome) to see if any errors are preventing the code from executing?

Comment: Check the console

Comment: Open your form tag before table tag, otherwise it looks ok

Comment: @GauravRai; The form needs to either be around the complete table, or completely inside a table cell. The latter is the case here, so that’s perfectly valid, and very unlikely to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: It seems like you have a problem with the closing tags for the form and the td. Try inverting `</td>` and `</form>`.

Answer (score 0):

your code works just fine maybe something in the js script preventing the action method. you should provide more information.